# 422 (Unprocessable Entity) ajax laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, ajax

estoy usando ajax con jquery en un formulario de una vista blade de laravel para crear cuentas de usuario (Auth) con laravel Fortify, pero me encuentro con el error 422 (Unprocessable Entity) que segun he leido es por unas validaciones que fallan, por lo cual revisando creo que deb ser esto, la validacion que esta en el CreateNeUser de Forify:

```
 public function create(array $input)
    {
        Validator::make($input, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => [
                'required',
                'string',
                'email',
                'max:255',
                Rule::unique(User::class),
            ],
            'password' => $this->passwordRules(),
        ])->validate();


        return User::create([
            'name' => $input['name'],
            'email' => $input['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($input['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

Mi ajax lo tengo asi:

```
 $('#formCuenta').submit(function(e){
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData(this);
        var name = $('name').text();
        var email = $('email').text();
        var password = $('password').text();
        //var password_confirm = $('#password-confirm').val();
        //var _token = $("input[name=_token]").val();
        $.ajax({
            url:"{{ route('cuenta.store')}}",
            type:"POST",
            data:{ formData },
                //password_confirm: password_confirm
                //_token:_token
                success:function(data){
                    if(data){
                        $('#formCuenta')[0].reset();
                        alert("Insertado con Exito");
                    }
                },


            contentType: false,
                processData: false,
        });

     });//fin
```

y el form asi:

```
<form id="formCuenta" > {{-- action="{{ route('registrar') }}" --}} {{-- action="{{ route('register.store') }}" method="POST" --}}
                @csrf
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <label for="name" class="form-label">{{ __('Nombre de Usuario') }}</label>
                        <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>
                        @error('name')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                        @enderror
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <label for="email" class="form-label">{{ __('Correo Electronico') }}</label>
                        <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror"  value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">
                        @error('email')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                        @enderror
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <label for="password" class="form-label">{{ __('Ingrese su Contraseña') }}</label>
                        <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" required autocomplete="new-password">

                        @error('password')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                        @enderror
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <label for="password-confirm" class="form-label">{{ __('Confirme Contraseña') }}</label>
                        <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control pa" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <button type="submit" id="btnCuenta" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">
                            {{ __('Crear Cuenta') }}
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <b><span class="text-success" id="success-message"> </span><b>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Las rutas las tengo asi (archivo web.php)

route::get('/register', [RegisteredUserController::class, 'create'])->name('registrar');
route::post('/registerS',[RegisteredUserController::class, 'store'])->middleware(['auth'])->name('cuenta.store');

Editado: ahora por consola me muestra el error: responseText: "{"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"password":["The password confirmation does not match."]}}", pero en las validaciones ese campo no esta, y por lo que veo tampoco se deberia enviar entre los parametros

Saludos a todos

Comment: por qué no imprimes con un console.log el catch de ajax, ahi te dira que parte dela validacion esta fallando

Comment: Seguramente la regla esté en `$this->passwordRules()`. ¿Si envías el campo `password_confirmation` funciona?